# Changing keybinding for org-capture

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-capture

I expect my reception to compile my daily agenda using .org capture. But they find using C-c C; C-c C-s; C-c C-c to capture, schedule and completion respectively **difficult.** 
Can a single function keys like a f6 f7and f8 be used instead of default keys. 
Kindly help

Comment: `org-capture` doesn't have any default keybinding, so if `C-c c` runs `org-capture` in your Emacs it's because of something you put yourself in your configuration. Go there and change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply